# Is there a word that means "this deal will not involve credit"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, business-language

I was buying a car, and the salesman started to talk about credit terms. I responded with "I'm paying cash", meaning that I didn't need any credit. However, the salesman was worried that I was about to produce a briefcase full of banknotes.

Is there a word other than "cash" to mean "immediate payment in full, without any credit being extended"?

Comment: "I won't be needing financing" is something that worked for me recently.

Comment: I agree. I would use some form of saying that the purchase will not be financed. Something like "I"m not financing it" or "I don't need financing".

Comment: Of course the salesman was worried. You just took away the nice big bonus he would have got from the loan company if you had taken out the "special offer finance package" (special for him, not you!) that he was going to sell you.

Comment: @alephzero No, he was worried about all the paperwork required to prove that the money wasn't the fruits of some criminal enterprise.

Comment: @PaulJohnson The word is "cash." The salesman was probably being disingenuous.  It's true that this is one of the many ambiguities of the English language. Should your listener be confused, you can then clarify with your actual payment method (check, cashiers check, etc.)

Comment: "I'll pay cash" is perfectly correct. However you often have to repeat it many (many) times in order to make it understood to a car salesman.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word ***cash*** itself suffices; however, this may cause ambiguity (as in your example) due to the *widely accepted* meaning of cash to mean *hard cash*.

From **ODO**:

> **[cash](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cash)**
> *NOUN*
>
> [MASS NOUN]
> **1** Money in coins or notes, as distinct from cheques, money orders, or credit: the staff were paid in cash a discount for cash
>
> **1.1** Money in **any form**: she was always short of cash
>
> [**hard cash**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hard-cash?q=hard%20cash)
> *NOUN*
>
> *[MASS NOUN]* Negotiable coins and banknotes as opposed to other forms of payment: hard cash may soon be back in fashion
>
> More example sentences
>
> In an uncertain world, many investors look to dividends - payouts in
> hard cash - to justify their decision to hold shares.
>
> I guess I never treated the credit card as hard cash and therefore I
> found it easier to justify and carry on spending.
>
> This will be credited as my investment in the company as opposed to
> putting in hard cash into Bordier [Bank].

If a phrase is acceptable, you may say (if at all required) that it's *cash but **not** hard cash*.

Also, ***cash down*** may fit the bill.

From **ODO**:

> **[cash down](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cash-down)**
>
> *British* With **immediate and full payment at the time of purchase**: the price was £900 cash down
>
> More example sentences
>
> But City said it would have to be cash down or nothing.
>
> ‘No one is walking in and putting ***cash down** on new cars*,’ said Pat
> Shanahan, owner of Isuzu dealership Airport Auto.

Comment: If I heard the term "cash down" I would assume that it meant paying the _down-payment_ of a car with a (much more reasonably sized) stack of paper money.

Comment: @Random832 yes, _cash down_ is _full down-payment_, not necessarily using _hard_ cash..

Comment: @alwayslearning In the US, "cash down" would be understood to refer to the portion of the cost of the car not being financed. An American would not use the term "cash down" except in relation to something being financed. For example "zero cash down" means that there is no initial payment and the entire cost is financed.

Answer (score 20):

"I'm paying up front." This means that you are paying the full amount before taking ownership of the car.

Comment: This is the obvious answer to me but speaking Australian English, sometimes I'm at odds with other answers here.  Is this sense of the phrase only used in the Southern Hemisphere?

Comment: @JoelRoberts: Perhaps not common in Canada (but neither is *paying up front* anymore), but certainly a phrase I would expect to be commonly understood. I cannot speak for the U.S.

Comment: @JoelRoberts Amazon Web Services use this expression on their admin console

Comment: @JoelRoberts Sounds fine to my American ear, though it has more of a connotation of paying now for delivery of goods or services later. It might be a little odd if used, by itself, for a situation where money and goods are exchanged more-or-less simultaneously. But in context - when used in contrast to paying through a loan - it would be perfectly understandable.

Comment: Is it up front or up-front/ upfront?

Comment: @RamPillai: it's _up front_ in the predicative position, as here; but _up-front_ in the attributive position, as in "I made an up-front payment."

Comment: @TonyK: I couldn't find what you mentioned as 'up front' when I searched for it.  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/upfront;

Comment: @RamPillai: You didn't look very hard! Your link has "_adverb_ Also **up front**." Also [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/up_front).

Comment: Yes, that shows only in the heading; but the contents says 'up-front' @TonyK

Comment: @RamPillai: "Also **up front**" means that the dictionary is of the opinion that both forms are correct.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upfront:  Perhaps you said different contexts for it mentioning predicative use and attributive use. That is fine @TonyK: Perhaps I am wrong, but if I use usages like "You are wrong", please correct me.

Answer (score 16):

"I'm paying cash" is a common, widely recognized euphemism to indicate you do not want to make payments. You could pay by cheque, bank transfer or even with a suitcase of cash if you so wished. In most countries, cash is still "legal tender". The salesman's concerns were totally inappropriate and it would have been good to talk to someone more experienced like the sales manager or owner.

I think it's a bad idea to defer to the a salesman's worries by changing commonly accepted terms. However, you could simply say, "I don't need credit terms since I'm paying in full".

Comment: Great first answer! Welcome to ELU. I would like to see you answer more questions. Do [sign up](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/signup). :)

Comment: @NVZ Not that I disagree, but aren't these kinds of answers usually dinged for lack of research, no citations to reliable sources, and the inclusion of commentary? Like the "suitcase of cash", which the dealership doesn't have to accept (at least in the US).

Comment: It's important to note that businesses are not required to accept cash payments - see [this answer](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7701/is-it-illegal-to-refuse-us-currency-for-a-purchase).

Comment: Please note that the US may or may not be included in "most countries". Because of the international nature of English, this site is not necessarily limited to the United States, or even North America.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Meant to include that in my comment - thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Be careful with the term "legal tender". It refers to a detailed set of rules about the payment of debts and has almost nothing to do with routine commerce.